# JavaScript prompt() won't work in AppJS

Tags: javascript, prompt, appjs

I'm making an app in AppJS, and the `prompt()` function wont work. I've looked it up, tried `window.prompt()` and many other things, but nothing has worked. I'm trying to see when the Esc key is pressed, then the person enters the password. If the password is correct, then the it will run `window.close()`. The `prompt` box does not popup.

```
window.addEventListener('keydown', function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 27){
        var pw = prompt('Please enter the password.');
        if(pw == 'password') window.close();
    }
}, false);
```

Comment: > AppJS project has not been actively developed for a few years. Please check out NW.js or Electron instead.

Comment: *"Websites please."* Is searching *really* that hard?

Comment: I've been working in AppJS, and now how it works. I don't fell like learning a new JS. Is there a way to use `prompt()` in AppJS?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I need to use AppJS, because the app i'm working on is a 'Kids only play ABCYa.com games' and don't mess up your computer. AppJS allows you to not display the normal window controls, and I need a way to close it, and not have button with an 'X', kids now to press that to close it, and they need to only stay on ABCYa.com.

Answer (score 3):

AppJS has overridden the default `window.prompt` method.

Here is the Google groups discussion [thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/appjs-dev/hddReOpEiYU).

Comment: Is there a different function like `window.prompt()` that I could use?

Comment: Use a modal library, to show an input field and a submit button. You can handle the submit as required.

Comment: Could I just make my own?

Comment: Yes, you can. Here is a reference. [Link 1](http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2012/10/creating-a-modal-window-with-html5-and-css3/) [Link 2](http://jsfiddle.net/raving/1mhsynmw/)